# Index Python Print Statement

Tags: python, ubuntu

I have code that takes logfile input, line by line, parses it, and creates formatted output.

Each line of the input is similar to `"12|15|joe|2|N|15| | |"`.

The output should be ...

```
1 12 OK--- 15|joe|2|N|15| | 
2 15 NO--- 12|2|N|15|3| 
3 12 OK--- 15|joe|2|N|15| |
```

However my code is printing...

```
line 12OK--- 15
line 12OK--- 15  
line 15NO--- 12
line 15NO--- 12
```

Here is my code:

```
import sys
import os
import re

print ("hello");
filename= "data.txt"
mydata= []
with open(filename, "r") as f:

 next(f)

 index = 1
 logic = True
 for i in f:

    st = i.split('|')

    if len(st) == 1:
        break

    record_number= st[0]
    size=st[1]
    username=st[2]
    transaction=st[3]
    field_type=st[4]
    numeric_value=st[5]
    character_value=st[6]
    date_value=st[7]

    if field_type == 'N':
        if character_value != ' ' or date_value != ' ' or                   numeric_value == ' ':
            logic=False

    elif field_type == 'C':
        if numeric_value != ' ' or date_value != ' ' or character_value == ' ':
        logic=False

    elif field_type == 'D':
        if numeric_value != ' ' or character_value != ' ' or date_value == ' ':

        logic=False

    new_st = st[0] + '|' + st[1] + '|' + st[2] + '|' + st[3] +' |' + st[4] + '|' + st[5] + '|' + st[6] + '|' + st[7]+'|'

    if logic:
        print("line " + st[0] + "OK--- " + st[1])
    else:
        print ("line " + st[1] + "NO--- " + st[0])

    index = index + 1
```

What is the problem with the code?

Comment: Please add some sample input data.

Comment: You're only printing `st[0]` and `st[1]`. The rest of your line is in `new_st`

Comment: What are you using the variable `index` for?

Comment: I was trying to use index so it would print line 1, line 2, line 3, and  the index would increment.

Comment: .txt file 12|15|joe|2|N|15| | |

Comment: output for that line should be line 1 OK --- 12|15|joe|2|N|15| | |

Comment: It should be able to be removed from `hold` status now.

Answer (score 0):

This is much cleaner, and faster code (`str + str + str` is slow :) )

I hope it covers all the things you want to do...

```
line = 0
for i in f:
    line += 1
    #=== this is probably not needed. File will stop producing data when it reaches the last line
    # if len(i) < 1:
    #     break
    #===========================================================================

    record_number, size, username, transaction, field_type, numeric_value, character_value, date_value = i.split('|')

    # Default, assuming nothing comes of the if/then cascade
    line_to_print = "{} {} OK--- {}|{}|{}|{}|{}|{}|{}".format(line, record_number, size, username, transaction, field_type, numeric_value, character_value, date_value)

    if field_type == 'N':
        if character_value != ' ' or date_value != ' ' or numeric_value == ' ':
            line_to_print = "{} {} NO--- {}|{}|{}|{}|{}|{}|{}".format(line, size, record_number, transaction, field_type, numeric_value, character_value, date_value)

    elif field_type == 'C':
        if numeric_value != ' ' or date_value != ' ' or character_value == ' ':
            line_to_print = "{} {} NO--- {}|{}|{}|{}|{}|{}|{}".format(line, size, record_number, transaction, field_type, numeric_value, character_value, date_value)

    elif field_type == 'D':
        if numeric_value != ' ' or character_value != ' ' or date_value == ' ':
            line_to_print = "{} {} NO--- {}|{}|{}|{}|{}|{}|{}".format(line, size, record_number, transaction, field_type, numeric_value, character_value, date_value)

    print(line_to_print)
```

**And even a little more pythonic:**

```
def makeLineToPrint(ok):
    if ok:
        line_to_print = "{} {} OK--- {}|{}|{}|{}|{}|{}|{}".format(line, record_number, size, username, transaction, field_type, numeric_value, character_value, date_value)

    else:
        line_to_print = "{} {} NO--- {}|{}|{}|{}|{}|{}".format(line, size, record_number, transaction, field_type, numeric_value, character_value, date_value)

    return line_to_print

line = 0
for i in f:
    line += 1
    #=== this is probably not needed. File will stop producing data when it reaches the last line
    # if len(i) < 1:
    #     break
    #===========================================================================

    record_number, size, username, transaction, field_type, numeric_value, character_value, date_value = i.split('|')

    # Default, assuming nothing comes of the if/then cascade    
    line_to_print = makeLineToPrint(ok = True)    

    if field_type == 'N':
        if character_value != ' ' or date_value != ' ' or numeric_value == ' ':
            line_to_print = makeLineToPrint(ok = False)        

    elif field_type == 'C':
        if numeric_value != ' ' or date_value != ' ' or character_value == ' ':
                line_to_print = makeLineToPrint(ok = False)        

    elif field_type == 'D':
        if numeric_value != ' ' or character_value != ' ' or date_value == ' ':
            line_to_print = makeLineToPrint(ok = False)        

    print(line_to_print)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
1 12 OK--- 15|joe|2|N|15| | 
2 15 NO--- 12|2|N|15|3| 
3 12 OK--- 15|joe|2|N|15| |
```

Comment: thanks! but do you know i can increment the "line" every time it prints

Comment: See changes above :)

Comment: thank you so much, i am very new to python so i was really struggling

Comment: No worries. If it helped, please mark it as an answer.

Comment: Im getting an error "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 8)"

Comment: That error is probably from this line, `record_number, size, username, transaction, field_type, numeric_value, character_value, date_value = i.split('|')`, It's splitting on the `|`, and is expecting 8 values after the split. One of the `i` input lines has too many `|` in it. I.e. ``s = "12|15|joe|2|N|15| | |" will split into 9 items `['12', '15', 'joe', '2', 'N', '15', ' ', ' ', '']``. `12|15|joe|2|N|15| | ` will split into 8. You should probably verify that each line of your data coming in has the same number of `|`, and whether your input line has 8 values or 9.

Comment: More simply if your input line has an `|` at the end, with no useful data afterwards the split will attempt to add an empty value at the end of the split. If there's no useful data after the last `|` just add a junk variable to the end of `record_number, size, username, transaction, field_type, numeric_value, character_value, date_value, junk = i.split('|')`

Comment: the junk variable helped and now the program runs correctly, thank you!